# Android scale item height of RecyclerView with StaggeredGridLayoutManager to match column width

Tags: android, imageview, android-recyclerview, staggered-gridview, staggeredgridlayout

I am using RecyclerView with StaggeredGridLayoutManager in vertical orientation. Item of the RecyclerView contains only one view - ImageView.  I would like the ImageView height to scale to match RecyclerView's column width and keep aspect ratio of photo that it contains. Currently parameters of this image view are:

    `android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"`

but the height of the item in RecyclerView matches original height of the photo and the photo is just centered. 
How is it possible to achieve that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this attribute to your `ImageView`:

```
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

[Image View | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setAdjustViewBounds(boolean))